# MSBuild SonarQube Runner v1.0 returns with code 1 after "Generating the FxCop ruleset"

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I'm trying out SonarQube using the new MSBuild SonarQube Runner v1.0. If I install a fresh SonarQube server locally, the following command works fine, and I can build my solution directly afterward, call the 'end' command, and have the results published in SonarQube:

`MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /key:TestKey /name:TestName /version:1.0.0.0`

However, if I run this against an existing SonarQube server that exists on the internal network, it always returns with exit code 1:

`15:32:40  Creating config and output folders...
15:32:40  Creating directory: c:\Test\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0.itsonar\.sonarqube\conf
15:32:40  Creating directory: c:\Test\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0.itsonar\.sonarqube\out
15:32:41  Generating the FxCop ruleset: c:\Test\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0.itsonar\.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeFxCop-cs.ruleset
Process returned exit code 1`

It seems to download a lot of the dependencies into /.sonarqube, so communication with the server isn't an issue

Things I've tried:

- checked the access.log, server.log and event logs
- upgraded the existing server to v5.1.2 (clean install using the guide)
- upgraded the sonar-csharp-plugin to v4.1
- right-clicked all .jar files on the server and ensured they are unblocked
- tried the runner directly on the server
- (ongoing) tried debugging the source code (happening somewhere in the pre-process step: `success` comes back as `true`, but the error code is 1)
- disabled UAC on the server an rebooted
- re-installed JRE on both server and client, ensure `JAVA_HOME` in both `PATH` and registry are set correctly

Any help or pointers greatly accepted. I've been stuck on this for 2 days and can't think of anything else to try except continue trawling through source code. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is a tricky one! Looking at the code, I see only one path that can yield this output:

1. It fails while generating the FxCop ruleset for C#, as the VB.NET FxCop ruleset message is not logged - see [TeamBuildPreProcessor.cs#L149](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-msbuild-runner/blob/1.0/SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor/TeamBuildPreProcessor.cs#L149) and [TeamBuildPreProcessor.cs#L185](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-msbuild-runner/blob/1.0/SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor/TeamBuildPreProcessor.cs#L185)
2. The `GenerateFxCopRuleset()` call for C# threw a `WebException`, leading to the call of `Utilities.HandleHostUrlWebException()` - which has to return `true` for the exception to be silently swallowed - see [Utilities.cs#L153](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-msbuild-runner/blob/1.0/SonarQube.Common/Utilities.cs#L153)
3. The only path returning `true` without logging any message is if a `HttpStatusCode.NotFound` was received - see [Utilities.cs#L158](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-msbuild-runner/blob/1.0/SonarQube.Common/Utilities.cs#L158)
4. The control flow goes back to `FetchArgumentsAndRulesets()`, which returns `false`, then goes back to `Execute()` which returns `false` as well - see [TeamBuildPreProcessor.cs#L106](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-msbuild-runner/blob/1.0/SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor/TeamBuildPreProcessor.cs#L106)
5. The MSBuild SonarQube Runner "begin" phase (called "preprocessor" in the code) fails - see [Program.cs#L42](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-msbuild-runner/blob/1.0/SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor/Program.cs#L42)

So, at some point, some SonarQube web service required for the C# FxCop ruleset generation is return a HTTP 404 error.

Could you monitor your network traffic and listen for the failing HTTP call? [I will keep on updating this answer afterwards]

EDIT: Indeed the error is caused by the quality profile name containing special characters. Such characters are currently badly URL-escaped, which leads to a 404.

I've created the following ticket to fix this issue in the upcoming release: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-125

Comment: Hi Dinish, thanks for your input. I managed to find the issue last night using your pointers, but it was a little unexpected: In `Quality Profiles`, there was an existing `C#` default profile named 'Sonar+Resharper'. I replaced the `+` from the name with a space `Sonar Resharper`, and now the registration / begin command works from the runner.

Comment: I faced the same issue as Warren described in his question. Apparently I had my Quality Profile named as `xxxx C#`. After I removed the `#` from profile name it worked liked a charm.

Comment: Thanks - I've edited my answer and created a ticket to fix the bad URL escaping in the next release.

Comment: @Dinesh-SonarSourceTeam can you please look into this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027524/sonar-fxcop-results-not-displayed

Comment: @Dinesh-SonarSourceTeam Please the new questions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004565/sonar-dashboard-not-updated-after-fxcop-analysis